# Prototype stops executing statements in dom:loaded if a null object is encountered

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

It looks to me that Prototype stops executing statements wrapped inside the dom:loaded event if a null object is encountered.  For example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
       //id below does not exist in the DOM
       $('invalid_id').observe('click',function(e){Event.stop(e);//do something});
       //alert box will not execute.
       alert('do something');
    });
 </script>
```

will raise errors in IE while other browsers (Chrome, FF, etc.) will silently ignore the error, but any lines below the error won't be executed.

JQuery doesn't seem to behave this way.  Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#invalid_id").click(function(event){
          //click event code here...
       });
       alert('do something');
    });
 </script>
```

...will continue executing lines even if a null object is encountered.

I have been unable to find anything on Prototype's website about this issue, while JQuery does address it.  Has anyone else experienced this or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('invalid_id').observe(...` is throwing an error if an element with id `invalid_id` does not exist.

If you want to do it the way jquery works (where it will work regardless if invalid_id exist or not) use:

```
$$('#invalid_id').invoke('observe','click',function(e){...});
```

this way the rest of your on dom loaded function will execute.